How to suspend battens from ceiling joists for attic insulation?
I live in the colder climate and need more insulation about 35cm (14") of rockwool and a layer of polyurethane (PIR in my region) board, which serves as a vapor barrier as well.
Due to specific rafter construction I can only put about 15 cm (6") of rockwool insulation between the rafters without leaving some air gaps.
So in addition to 15 cm (6"), I need to ad 20 cm (8") of rockwool insulation under the rafters. The question is how to fix it in place. The last layer of insulation is Polyurethane boards (PIR or PUR), the one with aluminium.
The plan for my pitched roof insulation is 15 cm of rock wool between lower part of the rafters. Then I need to install perpendicular battens to fit additional 20 cm of rock wool. Last I will instal 5 cm PIR boards.
How do I instal 20cm x 5cm battens? Simply with a 25 cm screws? Will this be enough for hold the weight of batten, wool and plaster?



You need to supply a diagram for this. I don't understand why you need 20cm x 5cm (8" x 2") battens. You are needing to support 35cm (14") of Rockwood which is about 7.5 kg/SM (1.5lbs/sf). Drywall is about the same. What is PIR? Does your building code require a vapour barrier?

I get the impression that you're attaching more insulation under the ceiling joists. Why? Why would you not put it all in the attic? There's plenty of space.

Similarly, why not put up a ceiling, and blow insulation into the space between a ceiling and roof? Or fasten sheets of foam insulation across the bottom of the rafters, and then fasten wallboard over it to create the ceiling surface and fire barrier? Or both, for that matter. It feels like you are making this more complicated than it has to be.

I would hang them with vertical posts attached to your trusses.

Snap chalk lines across the existing framing to establish batten location.

Attach 40mmx40mm or larger vertical members to each truss along each line using adequate nails or screws. Use a bubble level so each is accurately vertical.

Attach your new members to these verticals.
PLAN (TOP) VIEW



              | | <-- batten
              | |
    --------------------------------------------- 
    ---------------------------------------------
              | ||_|    ^-- ceiling joist (truss bottom chord)
              | | ^-- vertical post
              | |        

All fasteners should be in shear when you're complete. You will not rely on the pullout hold of any fasteners other than in your finish sheathing.
